# Can't read data in Postman, but works when using axios

Tags: php, json, axios, postman, x-www-form-urlencoded

Currently building a restful API just to practice, but one thing I've noticed is that depending on how I read it, it'll either throw errors, give no results or actually work. Frontend is React using the axios library to make requests. Backend is just plain PHP.

I have two ways of reading,

1. `file_get_contents("php://input")`
   When I make a request from the frontend, I'm able to read the formdata and use it.
   However when I send in Postman it returns nothing. People recommended using `x-www-form-urlencoded` and so I tried it, but the result is the same. Someone else recommended reading with the superglobals
2. `$_POST['item']`
   In postman it's able to read the data no problem, but if I send with axios, it throws an undefinded array key warning.

I'd like to be able to test the api as I build it using Postman without having to change it later on when I incorporate it within the actual app. Clueless from this point on so any suggestions would be helpful. Apologies if I'm doing something stupid

Axios part :

```js
let fdata = {
  email: "testemail",
  achternaam: "testachternaam",
};

axios
  .post("http://localhost/api/test", fdata)
  .then((result)=>{
    console.log(result.data)
})
```

PHP Part

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Contro-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Authorization ,X-Requested-With");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

print_r($data json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))); // this works in with axios, but doesn't work with postman

echo $email = $_POST['email'];
// works in postman, but not with axios
```

In Postman I send the exact same in `formdata` and also
`x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image: Postman Request]

Comment: Presumably you're doing something different in axios than you are in postman...maybe sending the data a different way and/or in a different format. We can only guess since you haven't provided many details. A [mre] of the issue is usually needed for us to answer the question objectively. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. We'd want sample data, the Axios code, the postman request (screenshot or maybe an export of the config), and the PHP code which is supposed to read the incoming input. Thanks.

Comment: i hope that I've provided enough, if anything is up let me know. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios automatically converts data you pass into `.post()` into JSON format (see https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example). By contrast, your PostMan request sends form-url-encoded data (where the keys and values are encoded in key-value tuples separated by `&`, with a `=` between the key and the value, e.g. `email=testemail&achternaam=testachternaam`).

These are different formats, and PHP reads them in different ways. `json_decode` can't work on non-JSON data, but conversely only form-encoded data is added to `$_POST` automatically.

To send equivalent data from Postman, to be the same as your Axios request, change the format to "raw" and then paste

```
{
  "email": "testemail",
  "achternaam": "testachternaam",
}
```

in there, and select JSON as the format.

Comment: Ohh, that makes a lot of sense. I've tested it and it works. Thank you for the thorough explanation.